# I want to exit a class and then run some code in python

Tags: python, class, oop

```py
X = int(input('Press 1 to run the code and Press 2 to exit: '))
class main:
    pass
     #here I want the program to quit
     
if X == 1:
    main
else:
    quit()
```

Comment: Why would you use a class here in the first place, when you should have a function? Anyway, there would be much too much to cover here, so I really advise you to have another look at your learning material or to go through a good basic Python tutorial, that would be a great help for you - SO is not meant to replace that.

Comment: You shouldn't use `quit` anyway. To cite the [documentation of `quit` and `exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Code runs from top to bottom and python "will" execute the body of the class (in contrast to function). So if you exit there, the program terminates.

We don't use classes to control the flow of a program. Instead use function if you want to achieve this.

Also if you don't have any code after the last `if` , then there is no need to use `quit()`. It will quit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make an object that runs some code then why not make a function instead than rather having to use classes, classes are usually used for making multiple objects of something and isnt used to quit a program.